# How to fix white space issue in wordpress revision post?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have create a post revision in wordpress but I am getting white space issue in word-press revision for a post. Please help me to sort out this issue

[Post revision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sy20.png)

[Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1yc1.png)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of the issue is that (at least) one of the PHP scripts in the Theme’s code has extra blank lines at the beginning or end. When these scripts are loaded, the extra lines are appended to any output.

I’m afraid that you will need to contact the developers of your theme and ask them to investigate and remove the extra whitespace.

In the meantime, you can download your backups directly from remote storage. Extra whitespace usually only affects the downloading of backup files through UpdraftPlus.

Comment: There is no space. I can share image with you for my html source code. https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1yc1.png

Comment: its actually very weird. but try removing the space between the " and the the prefix and try. please let me know what happens too. thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what i have to do?

Comment: im also not so sure but can you see the space after the " mark? try putting an _ mark afterwards and try